# wkhtmltopdf on nodejs generates corrupt pdfs

Tags: node.js, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to generate pdfs in nodejs

Below is my sample code to generate pdf

```
var  wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf')
    , createWriteStream = require('fs').createWriteStream;

 var r =  wkhtmltopdf('http://www.google.com', { pageSize: 'letter' })
            .pipe(createWriteStream('C:/MYUSERNAME/demo.pdf'));

        r.on('close', function(){
            mycallback();
        });
```

The above code is generating corrupt pdfs. I could not figure out the issue.
Although when I generate pdfs using command prompt it is generating correctly
like when I use below code in windows command prompt

```
wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com demo.pdf
```

I get correct pdf generated,sadly when I try to generate pdf in node environment, it generates corrupt pdfs.

Incase it helps I'm using **wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0 rc2**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wkhtmltopdf for node has a bug for windows, so you can write a new one.

Like this:

```
function wkhtmltopdf(input, pageSize) {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

    var html;

    var isUrl = /^(https?|file):\/\//.test(input);
    if (!isUrl) {
        html = input;
        input = '-';
    }

    var args = ['wkhtmltopdf', '--quiet', '--page-size', pageSize, input, '-']
    if (process.platform === 'win32') {
        var child = spawn(args[0], args.slice(1));
    } else {
        var child = spawn('/bin/sh', ['-c', args.join(' ') + ' | cat']);
    }

    if (!isUrl) {
        child.stdin.end(html);
    }

    return child.stdout;
}

// usage:

createWriteStream = require('fs').createWriteStream;

wkhtmltopdf('http://google.com/', 'letter')
    .pipe(createWriteStream('demo1.pdf'));

wkhtmltopdf('<body>hello world!</body>', 'letter')
    .pipe(createWriteStream('demo2.pdf'));
```

**note:** the param is now 'letter' not { pageSize: 'letter' }

Comment: I am trying your code,will get back to you as soon as i can. Seems like only args is changed...?

Comment: it is working great now. But instead of google.com,when I m passing a parameter which contains html string, it is failing to generate the output.Any suggestions...?

Comment: I have used the same way,but my html is huge string,not sure why it is generating corrupt pdf.I will check with the new code.Thanks

Comment: my table rows are getting cut into half whenever page break occurs.any suggestions...?

Comment: also media print css doesnt seem to work,if you have sometime can you suggest something

Comment: I have tried phantomjs. It takes media print styles,but it has the same problem, that rows get cut into half,well basically both phantom and wkhtmltopdf are using webkit itself,so problem with webkit,maybe

Comment: how about 'A4' instead of 'letter'?

Comment: sadly the same issue with A4 too